# C# -> 7 in a string, convert to int returns 55?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, data-structures, char

Evening... revising some C# coding questions///

10 Random numbers
7319018271
....so I put brackets around the numbers and made it a string...
created an array with [10]...idea is to iterate through the string and convert each string var to an int and add to myArray...problem being...why does 7 return as 55?

[image]

Thanks

```
   var Numbers = "7319018271";

        int[] myArray = new int[10];

        for(int i = 0; i < Numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            myArray[i] = Numbers[Convert.ToInt32(i)];
        }

        int test = myArray[0];
```

Comment: Numbers[0] is the character '7', which has ASCII code 55. When you assign a character to an int it is converted to its ASCII code. You seem to be using `Convert.ToInt32` in the wrong place.

Comment: Do you mean `Convert.ToInt32(Numbers[i].ToString())` instead of `Numbers[Convert.ToInt32(i)]`? Because at the moment your code converts an `int` to an `int`, which makes little sense.

Comment: that has resolved the issue thanks for the help if you write up the answer ill mark it thanks again guys

Comment: All this would have been avoided with `myArray = new[]{7,3,1,9,0,1,8,2,7,1}`

Comment: Alternatively you can utilize this int/char equivalence c# supports: `myArray = numbers.Select(c => c-'0').ToArray()` - having a char '7' and subtracting char '0' from it results in number 7 - char '7' is at position 55 in the ascii table, char '0' is at 48, 55-48=7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain 55, that's the ASCII code for the *character* `7`.

The problem you have your code here is that you have `Convert.ToInt32` in the wrong place. Currently you're converting `i` (an `int`) to an `int`. The other issue is that passing a `char` to `Convert.ToInt32` will still result in `55`, so you need to first convert it to a `string`. Fixing both of these problems, we end up with the following:

```
myArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Numbers[i].ToString());
```